# Registration form phpmailer and e-mail length

Tags: email, phpmailer, string-length

First of all i'd like to apologise for my english. I am student from Poland and i don't know php but i need something from code. http://pastebin.com/x0vUhj8V

I have encoutered a problem. On my website i can't register with mail which is shorther than (i miss word but here is example) - **asd@wp.pl, asd@op.pl, asd@vp.pl**

it also concern the part which is before "@" mark (asd) and after (wp.pl, op.pl, vp.pl) -3characters is minimum what is accepted for example asd@asd.pl.

I think somewhere in the code is declareted minimum length of e-mail or something, but with my "knowledge" od PHP I can't figure out which part... If someone could explain me what should i change i would be gratefull. Please help

Edit: My fault, here is code http://pastebin.com/dhGgZkPB that is used to call phpMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Your English is just fine!

That version of PHPMailer is *really* old, over 10 years out of date. Get the latest from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/). Beyond that you have not posted the code you're using to call PHPMailer so we can't say what you're doing wrong - if you need somewhere to start, look at the documentation examples [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/).

There is no particular lower length limit on email messages or addresses (so long as they are valid) - you can quite reasonably send a message containing 'a' to someone at 'a@a.co'.